# This person wrote exciting stories for teens

Tags: grammar

1. This person wrote exciting stories for teens.
   [Does 'for teens' modify 'exciting stories' or 'wrote'? Is 'for teens' an adverbial phrase or an adjective phrase?]
2. She is a cook at a Chinese restaurant.
   [Does 'at a Chinese restaurant' modify 'a cook'? Can't it modify the verb 'is'? Is 'at a Chinese restaurant' an adjective phrase? Or can it be an adverbial phrase?]

Comment: It depends on what one means by 'modify'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an adjunct modify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275559/what-does-an-adjunct-modify)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't tell what *for teens* modifies.

Consider the following two sentences:

> She wrote exciting stories for reading aloud.
>   She wrote exciting stories for money.

*For reading aloud* modifies *stories*, because *she wrote for reading aloud* doesn't really make much sense. (You'd probably say *she wrote to be read aloud* instead.

*For money* modifies *wrote*, since *exciting stories for money* doesn't make much sense.

But in the OP's sentence, *for teens* could modify either *stories* or *wrote*, since both *stories for teens* and *wrote for teens* are reasonable. So it's ambiguous (not that it makes much difference to the meaning in this case).

2. In this case, *at a Chinese restaurant* almost certainly modifies *a cook*.

Why? Because we understand this sentence to mean *she works as a cook for a Chinese restaurant*. If the sentence were

> She is a politician at a Chinese restaurant,

then you could argue that *at a Chinese restaurant* modifies *is*. But almost nobody would understand the original sentence to mean *she is a cook who happens to be at a Chinese restaurant*, so in this case, we can safely say that context tells us that *at a Chinese restaurant* modifies *cook*.

Comment: I would say that _at a Chinese restaurant_ modifies neither the copula _is_ nor its noun phrase complement _a cook_, but the entire verb phrase _is a cook_. In “A cook at a Chinese restaurant was found murdered in her home last night”, it modifies the noun phrase, but here it makes more sense to say it’s the VP. Similarly, _for teens_ would either modify _wrote_ or the VP _wrote exciting stories_.

Answer (score 0):

**This person wrote exciting stories for teens.**

*Does 'for teens' modify 'exciting stories' or 'wrote'? Is 'for teens' an adverbial phrase or an adjective phrase?*

It's an adjective phrase. "What did she write?" The answer to a "what" question must be a noun: "Books for teens."

**She is a cook at a Chinese restaurant.**

- *Does 'at a Chinese restaurant' modify 'a cook'?* Yes.
- *Is 'at a Chinese restaurant' an adjective phrase?* Yes. It is a phrase describing "cook". If the sentence were "She is at a Chinese restaurant", then "at a Chinese restaurant" would be an adjective phrase modifying "she".
- *Can't it modify the verb 'is'?* No. (This is also why it cannot be an adverb phrase.) An adverb phrase in a sentence like this would be something like: "She is *without a doubt* a cook."

Comment: But what exactly is the grammatical difference between *"She wrote exciting stories for teens"* and *"She wrote exciting stories for money"*? Because *for money* is clearly an adverbial phrase in the second one.

Comment: Ooh, good point. I think in "for money", it answers the question, "Why did she write?" And the answer is "for [the purpose of getting] money". You could have "She wrote for teens", and in that case "for teens" would be an adverb phrase, but the sentence now means something else. Further evidence of this I think is that you can imagine a sign in a bookshop section: "Books for Teens". It's a noun phrase (noun + adjective phrase).